# Reading Data from Cloud Firestore from an Express API

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read four different documents from my firestore database collection. The code below works for the first function. However, the other end points return the same data from the first function and not their own data. When I remove the first function, the second function  works, but it would then have the same problem: the rest of the functions return the same data as the second one. Please help!

```
const db = require('../config/database');

module.exports = {
    major,
    specials,
    numbersPunctuation,
    extensions,
};


function major(req, res) {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const document = db.collection('Glyphs').doc('1');
            let item = await document.get();
            let response = item.data();
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
}

function specials(req, res) {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const document = db.collection('Glyphs').doc('2');
            let item = await document.get();
            let response = item.data();
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
}

function numbersPunctuation(req, res) {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const document = db.collection('Glyphs').doc('3');
            let item = await document.get();
            let response = item.data();
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
}

function extensions(req, res) {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const document = db.collection('Glyphs').doc('4');
            let item = await document.get();
            let response = item.data();
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
}
```

Comment: Try changing the const names, a const cannot change it's value, so very time is doing the same with the same document and it's not overriding the value.

Comment: Hey, that wasn't it. Apparently, the routing wasn't right. I was calling (/route/:1) instead of (/route/1). Thanks anyways!

Comment: Jonathan, you should post your answer with more details, then marked it as accepted

Comment: Alright, thanks Edgardo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after reviewing things carefully, I found out that the code works just fine. The reason I wasn't getting the data I wanted was because the routing (which is on a separate file) isn't done right. I had (route/:1) for (route/:id) instead of (route/1).